# Using Gradle plugin to push docker images to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using [gradle-docker-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) to build and push docker images to Amazon's ECR. To do this I am also using a remote docker daemon running on an EC2 instance. I have configured a custom task `EcrLoginTask` to fetch the ECR authorization token using `aws-java-sdk-ecr` library.  Relevant  code looks like : -

```
class EcrLoginTask extends DefaultTask {
    String accessKey
    String secretCode
    String region
    String registryId

    @TaskAction
    String getPassword() {
        AmazonECR ecrClient = AmazonECRClient.builder()
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretCode))).build()
        GetAuthorizationTokenResult authorizationToken = ecrClient.getAuthorizationToken(
                new GetAuthorizationTokenRequest().withRegistryIds(registryId))
        String token = authorizationToken.getAuthorizationData().get(0).getAuthorizationToken()
        System.setProperty("DOCKER_PASS", token) // Will this work ?
        return token
    }

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecr:1.11.244'
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.2.1'
    }
}



docker {
    url = "tcp://remote-docker-host:2375"
    registryCredentials {
        username = 'AWS'
        password = System.getProperty("DOCKER_PASS")    // Need to provide at runtime !!!
        url = 'https://123456789123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
    }
}

task getECRPassword(type: EcrLoginTask) {
    accessKey AWS_KEY
    secretCode AWS_SECRET
    region AWS_REGION
    registryId '139539380579'
}

task dbuild(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    dependsOn build
    inputDir = file(".")
    tag "139539380579.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/n6duplicator"
}

task dpush(type: DockerPushImage) {
    dependsOn dbuild, getECRPassword
    imageName "123456789123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/n6duplicator"
}
```

The remote docker connection works fine, ECR token is also fetched successfully and the `dbuild` task also gets executed successfully.

**PROBLEM**

The `dpush` task fails - "Could not push image: no basic auth credentials"

I believe this is because the authorization token received using the `EcrLoginTask` was not passed on to  in the `docker` configuration closure `password` property.

How do I fix it ? I need to provide the credentials on the fly each time the build is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the '[gradle-aws-ecr-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/double16/gradle-aws-ecr-plugin)'. It's able to get a fresh (latest) Amazon ECR docker registry token, during every AWS/Docker command call:

> All Docker tasks such as DockerPullImage, DockerPushImage, etc. that
>   are configured with the ECR registry URL will get a temporary ECR
>   token. No further configuration is necessary. It is possible to set
>   the registry URL for individual tasks.

This should work well alongside either the [gradle-docker-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/wiki) or Netflix's [nebula-docker-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-docker-plugin/wiki), which is also based on, and extends, the 'bmuschko' docker plugin.

The '[gradle-aws-ecr-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/double16/gradle-aws-ecr-plugin)' BitBucket homepage explains concisely how to configure both the AWS and ECR [URL] credentials.